# MYSQL - Fetch proper float values

Tags: php, mysql, types

I am changed data-type of 1 table field int to float for accept decimal values also

i am saving value as 0.05, 0.1

when i am fetching value with following query:

```
SELECT points from tbl_points where user_id=10
```

it returns me vaule like

```
0.0546565749
```

i am not getting why this is happening. i just want to display value as it saved to into table. i.e. 0.05 OR 0.1

please help me....

thanks in advance

Comment: what is datatype of your this value field in database?

Comment: What is the insert query you used ? And you can use the `ROUND` function.

Comment: @DhruvPathak  no round will make that  0

Comment: @Vickey, not it does not, try `SELECT ROUND(0.0546565749,2);`

Comment: @DhruvPathak  yes its the proper format

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `float` to `2 decimal` places i.e. `float(10,2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$tt = "105";
echo number_format((float)$tt, 2, '.', '');  // this will  output  105.00
```